# JQuery traversal given Javascript snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand traversal in JQuery. I have this snippet in Javascript which extracts document.forms[0].elements[0] . Could someone explain to me how to get the JQuery equivalent of this?

Comment: I'd say this should be an equivalent: `$('form:first :first-child')`

Comment: `$(document.forms[0].elements[0])` <- **tada**

Comment: @ClaudioRedi — No, given `<form><div><span><i><input></i></span></div></form>`, it would return every element except the form instead of just the input.

Comment: @adeneo  That does nothing to teach the OP how jQuery traversal works; the point is not to get a jQuery-wrapped final element, but to learn what (if any) alternatives jQuery provides for traversing like that.

Comment: @Quentin: ideend, for some reason I made up in my mind that he was looking for the first child of the form (input or not). Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

In jQuery, that would be:

```
$('form').eq(0).children("input[type!='image'], select, textarea").eq(0);
```

To break it down:

- `$('form')` selects all 'form' tags on the page
- `.eq(0)` limits the selection to just the first form in the set
- `.children('input[type!='image'], select, textarea')` gets all child nodes of that object that are `input`, `select` or `textarea` elements (not "image" type inputs, to strictly match the behavior of [`.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.elements)
- `.eq(0)` limits the selection to the first in the set; the first child

Comment: Similar to `.eq(0)` would be `.get(0)` but instead of the jQuery object you would get the actual dom element, just in case the HTMLElement is needed.

Comment: This wont' work if you have a label or anything first. The better answer is by @adeneo. http://jsfiddle.net/xyUd8/

Comment: Oh right, `elements` doesn't grab all children, just control elements. I'll update the solution.

Comment: @Kevkong True; if the bare HTMLElement is desired the last `.eq(0)` in the chain should become a `.get(0)`. It's unclear OP's original intent in that area, since they were focusing on traversal.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick

```
$('form:first :input[type!="image"]:first')
```